# How to display evolving BufferedImage on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, bufferedimage

I need to display evolving BufferedImages on a JPanel. The code is structured in the following format and I have compiled a SSCCE as below.

The following classes are in SSCCE1 project in Eclipse

**Class DisplayLattice.Java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;   
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DisplayLattice extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage IMAGE = null;
    private BufferedImage DISPLAY_IMAGE = null;

    public DisplayLattice()
    {
        IMAGE = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        render();
    }

    public DisplayLattice(BufferedImage map) {
        IMAGE = map;
        render();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (IMAGE == null)
            super.paint(g);
        else
            g.drawImage(IMAGE, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void render() {

    int cellWidth = 5;
    int cellHeight = 5;

        int imgW = IMAGE.getWidth();
        int imgH = IMAGE.getHeight();
        DISPLAY_IMAGE = new BufferedImage(imgW*cellWidth, imgH*cellHeight, 1);          
        Graphics2D g2 = IMAGE.createGraphics();
        g2.clearRect(0,0,DISPLAY_IMAGE.getWidth(),DISPLAY_IMAGE.getHeight());

        for (int x=0; x<imgW; x++) {
            for (int y=0; y<imgH; y++) {
                g2.setColor(new Color(IMAGE.getRGB(x, y)));
                g2.fillRect((int)(x*cellWidth), (int)(y*cellHeight),
                            (int)cellWidth, (int)cellHeight);
            }
        }
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.dispose();
        repaint();
        revalidate();
        System.out.println("XX");
    }   

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image)
    {
        IMAGE = image;
    }
}
```

**Class SelfOrganizingMap.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class SelfOrganizingMap {

    public void methodTrain()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            new DisplayLattice(exportImageNorm());
        }

    }

    private BufferedImage exportImageNorm()
    {
        BufferedImage colorNodes = new BufferedImage(200, 200, 1);
        double[][] normL2values = new double[200][200];
        float t = 0.0f;
        for(int i = 0; i < normL2values.length ; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < normL2values[0].length; j++){
                t = (float) Math.random();
                colorNodes.setRGB(i, j, (new Color(t,t,t)).getRGB());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("LL");
        return colorNodes;
    }

}
```

The following class is in SSCCE2 project

**Class MapScreen.Java (Main Class)**

```
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class MapScreen extends JFrame {
    private int WIDTH = 0;
    private int HEIGHT = 0;
    private DisplayLattice pnlMap;

    public MapScreen(int mapOption) {


        setType(Type.UTILITY);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Map");
        setSize(600, 600);
        setLocation(150,150);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        pnlMap = new DisplayLattice();
        pnlMap.setBounds(6, 130, 582, 440);
        getContentPane().add(pnlMap);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                new SelfOrganizingMap().methodTrain();
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(10, 81, 89, 23);
        getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                MapScreen frame = new MapScreen(5);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is when I click the JButton on the MapScreen class I need the JPanel which is a instance of DisplayLattice in SSCCE1 project to dynamically change for the number of iterations as specified in the methodTrain() in the SelfOrganzingMap class.

The current problem I have is that the bufferedImage I set at the SelfOrganizingMap class at each iteration is not set in the JPanel displayed.

How to rectify this issue? What is the best way of doing this type of visualization keeping in mind that all three classes presented here is pretty huge in size with a lot of methods in the actual application.

Comment: While I take a deeper look, you might like to have a read of [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) as overriding `paint` isn't recommend ;)

Comment: Don't understand the point of you DisplayLattice class. You call the render() method and it creates a image, but I don't see where you use the image anywhere. There is no need to do a revalidate(). You do revalidate when you add/remove components from a panel. Also, you should be overriding the getPreferredSize() method to return the size of your image so the panel can be added to another panel and displayed at its proper size.

Comment: @camicker can you be more specific? The intention of creating the DisplayLattice is to enlarge what ever image is passed through to it so I can represent each array element with a rectangle. There is another part for the render method which calculates some values. I did not include it since that is not where my problem was. Sorry, if I mislead you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem (you are having) is in your `methodTrain` method.

```
new DisplayLattice(exportImageNorm());
```

This is simply creating a new instance of the `DisplayLattice`, which has nothing to do with the one that is actually been displayed on you screen...

The simplest solution I can think of is to simply pass the reference you created in `MapScreen` to the `methodTrain` method...

```
new SelfOrganizingMap().methodTrain(pnlMap);
```

This would allow you to do something like...

```
public void methodTrain(DisplayLattice map) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        map.setImage(exportImageNorm());
    }
}
```

The only other thing you would need to do after that is add `repaint` in the `setImage` method after you reassign the image.

**Nit picks**

- Don't use `setBounds`, use a `LayoutManager`, seriously, just make the effort, it will reward you endlessly...
- Don't override `paint`, use `paintComponent` instead.  This is the recommend method for providing custom painting.  Also, unless you absolutely have a concrete reason not to, you MUST call `super.paintXxx` and if you don't, you better know what's going to go wrong so you can fix it.
- There's no need to call `revalidate` after `repaint`, `revalidate` will schedule a `repaint` itself.
- You also may like to take a look at [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: +1, I was just getting to the methodTrain() method, but now I don't have to worry.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Thanks for the quick reply. I now can get an image on the JPanel update once. But the above fix only displays the image after all the iterations are complete. But I need to display the generated image at each iteration not at the end of all iterations.

Comment: Do you want it animated or do you want the output pane to display each image (like in a grid)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I want image generated at each iteration to be displayed. So it will form a type of animation when images are replaced with subsequent images generated. So each image generated at each iteration should be updated to the same panel space. I don't want a grid so I can see all images. The output should look something like [this](http://davis.wpi.edu/~matt/courses/soms/applet.html) in the applet once you hit the play button

Comment: The problem you have is you are generating the the images within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, which is responsible for, amongst other things, processing repaint requests.  So, until the `actionPerformed` method actually exists, no repaints can occur. You have two choices, you can use a `javax.swing.Timer` that on each "tick" would generate a new image or use `SwingWorker` and use the `publish`/`process` methods to update the image. Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details